# eBay SDK not recognizing sandbox user account

Tags: python, sandbox, ebay-api

This is the contents of my `ebay.yaml` file:

```
name: ebay_api_config


# Trading API Sandbox - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/trading-api
api.sandbox.ebay.com:
    compatability: 719
    appid: XXXXXXXXXX
    certid: XXXXXXXXXX
    devid: XXXXXXXXXXX
    token: XXXXXXXXXXX
```

I'm using the exact file from https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/samples/trading.py to try to test my new Sandbox account, and the majority of the functions are working successfully, however I get following errors when trying to run VerifyAddItem function:

```
Call Success: 4670 in length
Response code: 200
Response DOM1: <DOM Element: GetFeedbackResponse at 0x101281170>
Response ETREE: <Element GetFeedbackResponse at 0x10124d050>
Response dictionary: {'FeedbackScore': '0', 'Ack': 'Success', 'Timestamp': '2018-06-11T18:09:11.892Z', 'Version': '1003', 'FeedbackSummary': {'NegativeFeedbackPeriodArray'...
Response Reply: {'FeedbackScore': '0', 'Ack': 'Success', 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 18, 9, 11), 'Version': '1003', 'FeedbackSummary': {'NegativeFeedb
Sell more, buy more..
u"VerifyAddItem: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 120, You need to create a seller's account. Before you can list this item we need some additional information to create a seller's account."
{'Ack': 'Failure', 'Timestamp': '2018-06-11T18:09:13.751Z', 'Errors': [{'SeverityCode': 'Warning', 'ErrorClassification': 'RequestError', 'ErrorCode': '21920200', 'LongMessage': 'Return Policy Attribute returnDescription Not Valid On This Site', 'ErrorParameters': {'_ParamID': '0', 'Value': 'returnDescription'}, 'ShortMessage': 'Return Policy Attribute Not Valid'}, {'ErrorCode': '21919158', 'LongMessage': "The email address you entered isn't linked to a PayPal account. If you don't have a PayPal account, you'll need to set one up with this address so that buyers can pay you. (You can set up your account after your item sells).", 'ErrorClassification': 'RequestError', 'SeverityCode': 'Warning', 'ShortMessage': 'Invalid PayPal email address.'}, {'ErrorCode': '120', 'LongMessage': "Before you can list this item we need some additional information to create a seller's account.", 'ErrorClassification': 'RequestError', 'SeverityCode': 'Error', 'ShortMessage': "You need to create a seller's account."}], 'Version': '1061', 'Build': 'E1061_UNI_API5_18724070_R1'}
```

I have set up a Sandbox account, have the user testuser_XXXXX with a valid password set up. And I had a successful response to GetTokenStatusResponse function:

```
Call Success: 449 in length
Response code: 200
Response DOM1: <DOM Element: GetTokenStatusResponse at 0x1012dc320>
Response ETREE: <Element GetTokenStatusResponse at 0x1012d7bd8>
Response dictionary: {'Ack': 'Success', 'Timestamp': '2018-06-11T18:09:14.347Z', 'Version': '1031', 'Build': 'E1031_CORE_APISIGNIN_18564253_R1', 'TokenStatus': {'Status': ...
Response Reply: {'Ack': 'Success', 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 18, 9, 14), 'Version': '1031', 'Build': 'E1031_CORE_APISIGNIN_18564253_R1', 'TokenStatu
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to have the SDK recognize my Sandbox user account. Is there something I need to put in `ebay.yaml` or in the GitHub script in addition to what's already there?`

I've tried using both kinds of tokens... using OAuth token doesn't work at all. So for these tests I've been using Auth'n'Auth

Comment: I hope you don't have the indentation before `api.sandbox.ebay.com`, because it needs to be non-indented and at root level

Comment: I've cleared up the comments, but there were no spaces in the actual file.

Comment: "You need to create a seller's account. Before you can list this item we need some additional information to create a seller's account."
That suggest the sandbox account is not registered as a seller account, so this prevents further actions via this API.

Comment: Yes, I haven't been able to link my sandbox account to PayPal. I've tried asking in Developer forums several time and with no success. I've also reached out to PayPal to see if they can assist. It appears to be a know issue for several people.

Comment: Did you have a look at the recent rollout: https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/releasenotes.html#1061. I guess the description field has been deprecated; try to remove it.

Comment: Even with description commented out, it doesn't work -- this is an issue with tying the PayPal account to the Sandbox account.

Answer (score 1):

Usually provider has his own forum, and it is better to look there.

Please look [here](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/26703/additem-throwing-error-21916328-return-policy-valu.html). Looks like there is a problem with return policy, when adding item. Last comment says that it was working for long time, while it is broken now. From [here][2] you can say something about amount of time it can take. That is test environment.

I've tried to integrate with them long time ago, and decided not to - because of this kind of problems. I'll try to refresh my test, but I don't expect much input from that.